# Thread Interrupt in java

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I have the following questions, if I interrupt a thread in java, a process that is running 15 minutes, it will stop the process, stop the methods or will finish this process,and not  allow others continue in line?

I have a "thread" that will call a method that will do a comparison based "access" and "postgres" after it will insert in postgres, if I want to stop the thread that called this action, she will succeed the stop the process, or wait they finish?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? It will help to understand your problem.

Comment: Does a search for "java thread interrupt" turn up nothing? ([Trick question](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html), of course.)

Comment: Also, there's a catch in that you can't interrupt a method blocked on a socket read. (Unless it's using NIO, which the database drivers might not.) You have to close a socket to unblock it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not stop the thread unless the methods executing in it are willing to terminate when they receive the "interrupt" signal.  Methods that throw InterruptedException usually fall into this category.  Of course, all methods in the call chain need to cooperate in one way or another.

If your code does not call "interruptable" methods or has sections that don't call them for long periods, then make them check flag `Thread.isInterrupted()` periodically, and terminate clean and gracefully if it ever becomes `true`.  Same thing if you ever receive (and catch, which you should) `InterruptedException`s.

Your question can be improved, though, if your intent is more specific.  I was about to explain how the "thread interrupt" protocol works, but perhaps this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: I think the only solution will verify my methods in the situation you are in the thread, so i can stop those processes.

Comment: It is incorrect to state that interruption does nohing unless the thread is in a blocking method that throws InterruptedException. Interruption sets the interrupted flag on a thread. Some blocking methods may exit early by throwing an InterruptedException.

Comment: @bowmore  My phrase (or what I intended of it) is "It will do nothing **of what you mention**"

Comment: It's still not correct, it may very well respond promptly to interruption even when not in a blocking method. And when in a blocking method that throws InterruptedException, there is still no guarantee the thread will not simply ignore the exception.

Comment: @bowmore  Yes, by checking the interrupted flag, which is what I mention in my second paragraph.  Please post your own answer if your vision differs too much from other's.

Comment: There is already another answer that is factually correct, your first sentence needs correcting/rephrasing.

Answer (score 3):

When you "interrupt" a thread, it does one of three things (which are probably the same thing behind the scenes):

- If the thread is currently waiting, sleeping, or joining another thread, the interrupt will cause an `InterruptedException` to be thrown in the target thread.
- If the thread is blocked waiting on "interruptible I/O" (that is, operations on an implementation of `InterruptibleChannel`), a `ClosedByInterruptException` will be thrown.
- If it's not doing one of those things, then a flag will be set on the thread.  The thread can check that flag by calling `Thread.interrupted()` (which will immediately reset the flag)...but if it doesn't, the next call to `any_object.wait()`, `Thread.sleep()`, or `any_thread.join()`, and *perhaps* certain other blocking methods, will throw an exception.

All these exceptions, of course, are *checked* exceptions...which almost invariably means that there will be an exception handler nearby (which, unless the code was designed to be interruptible, will typically just ignore the exception and try the operation again).  And if the thread never waits, and never checks the interrupt flag, then interrupting it won't do much.

Also, if the thread is currently waiting on something outside the control of the JVM, the interrupt might not have any effect.  On some platforms (Windows comes to mind), Java has a hard time interrupting native code.

All those caveats can be summed up as:  If what you want is to kill off an unruly thread, this probably isn't the way to do it.  Truth is, there isn't a decent way to kill a thread without leaving your process in a potentially wacky state.  What you typically want in such cases is a separate process you can kill if it gets out of hand.

Answer (score 2):

From the [source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html):-

> An interrupt is an indication to a thread that it should stop what it
>   is doing and do something else. It's up to the programmer to decide
>   exactly how a thread responds to an interrupt, but it is very common
>   for the thread to terminate. This is the usage emphasized in this
>   lesson. A thread sends an interrupt by invoking interrupt on the
>   Thread object for the thread to be interrupted. For the interrupt
>   mechanism to work correctly, the interrupted thread must support its
>   own interruption.

Comment: @Giovane You can but you shouldn't because it does gods know what to its internal state and to unfinished operations.

Comment: I just want it to stop, and avoid unwanted processing by the user.

Comment: @Giovane The problem there is the "unwanted" part. Is "finishing up a transaction" unwanted?

Comment: @Giovane:- Thread.stop() method causes the thread to immediately throw a ThreadDeath exception, which usually stops the thread

Comment: @Giovane A good example  of this is a text editor's atomic save operation. Like all IO you want it to happen outside the GUI thread. Atomic saves work by writing the editor buffer out to a temporary file, then deleting the original file, and moving the temporary file to where the original was. If at any point during this you merely kill the thread doing the IO, the user loses data. This is why it's strongly encouraged to implement thread shutdowns in a cooperative way, even if it's more effort.

Comment: **A thread may use interruption for performing tasks other than cancellation and shutdown. Consequently, a thread should be interrupted only when its interruption policy is known in advance. Failure to do so can result in failed interruption requests.**

Comment: @Giovane  Not with "interrupt", though.  The "interrupt" protocol was designed for clean thread termination (but then the interrupted threads and methods need to collaborate).  The "unclean" methods @millimoose is surely referring to are `destroy` and `stop`.  `suspend` comes into the same problem.  You can try them, but at your own risk.  And, who knows?, perhaps your application behaves reasonably.

Comment: @Giovane That said, I guess a corollary is that `Thread.stop()` is fine as long as you're certain that at no point in what the thread is doing something would happen if it stopped executing. However, "at no point", as far as you need to care, means "between any two bytecodes / CPU instructions".

Comment: I was trying to use Thread.interrupt (), but it did not work, in my thread I call a method that has several children, and for me to be checking the status is complicated, but it seems that is the only solution.

Comment: @RahulTripathi  That's absolutely correct.  In fact, more than "interrupting" a thread, what you are doing is "sending a signal" to it.  Or "calling its attention".  The very usual is cancellation, though, but for save development this is something to be checked.

Comment: @Giovan  Try `.stop`, subject to all considerations above.